# Attempting to use Android AsyncTask to get a response from a server

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to learn how to use the AsyncTask class to authenticate the user whose account is stored on a remote server and database.

I am working from an example and so far I have this code:

```
package com.problemio;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity 
{
    private TextView textView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Show form for login_email
        final EditText loginEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);  
        String name = loginEmail.getText().toString();  

        // Show field for password  
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);  
        String text = password.getText().toString();                  

        // Show button for submit
        Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);   




        // Show options for create-profile and forgot-password




        submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {  
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
              String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
              String pass = password.getText().toString(); 
              sendFeedback(pass, email);
            }
        });        
    }


    public void sendFeedback(String pass , String email) 
    {  
        Log.d( "1" , pass );
        Log.d( "1" , email );

        // Go to db and check if these r legit
        // How do I do that? :)
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", email ));  
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass ));


    }          



    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
        {
            Log.d( "Inner class: " , "Doing stuff in background" );

            String response = "";
            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            textView.setText(result);
        }    
    }

        public void readWebpage(View view) 
        {
            DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
            task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.myurl.com" });
        }        
}
```

and I get some errors in the LogCat like:

```
02-23 10:51:45.587: D/AndroidRuntime(1670): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-23 10:51:45.587: D/AndroidRuntime(1670): CheckJNI is ON
02-23 10:51:47.037: D/AndroidRuntime(1670): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
02-23 10:51:47.118: W/ActivityManager(1180): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Problemio.apk
02-23 10:51:47.267: W/ActivityManager(1180): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Problemio.apk
02-23 10:51:47.467: I/PackageManager(1180): Removing non-system package:com.problemio
02-23 10:51:47.467: I/ActivityManager(1180): Force stopping package com.problemio uid=10041
02-23 10:51:47.467: I/ActivityManager(1180): Killing proc 1648:com.problemio/10041: force stop
02-23 10:51:47.477: W/ActivityManager(1180): Force removing ActivityRecord{4147f5d0 com.problemio/.LoginActivity}: app died, no saved state
02-23 10:51:47.518: I/ActivityManager(1180):   Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{413e9e98 com.problemio/.ProblemioActivity}
02-23 10:51:47.587: W/InputDispatcher(1180): channel '4160fcd8 com.problemio/com.problemio.ProblemioActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-23 10:51:47.587: E/InputDispatcher(1180): channel '4160fcd8 com.problemio/com.problemio.ProblemioActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-23 10:51:47.607: I/WindowManager(1180): WIN DEATH: Window{416096c0 com.problemio/com.problemio.LoginActivity paused=false}
02-23 10:51:47.637: I/WindowManager(1180): WIN DEATH: Window{4160fcd8 com.problemio/com.problemio.ProblemioActivity paused=true}
02-23 10:51:47.637: W/InputDispatcher(1180): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4160fcd8 com.problemio/com.problemio.ProblemioActivity (server)'
02-23 10:51:47.667: I/WindowManager(1180): WINDOW DIED Window{4160fcd8 com.problemio/com.problemio.ProblemioActivity paused=true}
02-23 10:51:47.707: E/InputDispatcher(1180): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=206, events=0x8
02-23 10:51:48.157: D/dalvikvm(1180): GC_CONCURRENT freed 527K, 9% free 12067K/13255K, paused 10ms+43ms
02-23 10:51:48.587: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(1180): setKernelCountSet(10041, 0) failed with errno -2
02-23 10:51:48.587: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(1180): setKernelCountSet(10009, 1) failed with errno -2
02-23 10:51:48.598: I/PackageManager(1180): Package com.problemio codePath changed from /data/app/com.problemio-1.apk to /data/app/com.problemio-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
02-23 10:51:48.667: I/PackageManager(1180): Running dexopt on: com.problemio
02-23 10:51:49.247: D/dalvikvm(1681): DexOpt: load 54ms, verify+opt 86ms
02-23 10:51:49.307: W/PackageManager(1180): Code path for pkg : com.problemio changing from /data/app/com.problemio-1.apk to /data/app/com.problemio-2.apk
02-23 10:51:49.317: W/PackageManager(1180): Resource path for pkg : com.problemio changing from /data/app/com.problemio-1.apk to /data/app/com.problemio-2.apk
02-23 10:51:49.327: I/ActivityManager(1180): Force stopping package com.problemio uid=10041
02-23 10:51:49.517: D/PackageManager(1180): New package installed in /data/app/com.problemio-2.apk
02-23 10:51:49.808: I/ActivityManager(1180): Force stopping package com.problemio uid=10041
02-23 10:51:49.997: D/dalvikvm(1275): GC_EXPLICIT freed 235K, 6% free 11344K/12039K, paused 5ms+13ms
02-23 10:51:50.177: D/dalvikvm(1341): GC_EXPLICIT freed 168K, 4% free 9389K/9735K, paused 105ms+9ms
02-23 10:51:50.646: D/dalvikvm(1180): GC_EXPLICIT freed 448K, 10% free 12001K/13255K, paused 83ms+18ms
02-23 10:51:50.728: D/PackageManager(1180): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged
02-23 10:51:50.897: D/PackageManager(1180): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged
02-23 10:51:50.929: D/BackupManagerService(1180): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.problemio flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
02-23 10:51:51.047: I/AccountTypeManager(1408): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 647ms(wall) 12ms(cpu)
02-23 10:51:51.117: D/PackageManager(1180): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged
02-23 10:51:51.217: D/PackageManager(1180): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged
02-23 10:51:51.357: D/BackupManagerService(1180): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.problemio flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
02-23 10:51:51.357: V/BackupManagerService(1180): updatePackageParticipantsLocked: com.problemio
02-23 10:51:51.697: W/RecognitionManagerService(1180): no available voice recognition services found
02-23 10:51:52.817: I/AccountTypeManager(1408): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 45ms(wall) 15ms(cpu)
02-23 10:51:52.919: D/BackupManagerService(1180): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.problemio flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
02-23 10:51:52.940: V/BackupManagerService(1180): updatePackageParticipantsLocked: com.problemio
02-23 10:51:53.977: D/dalvikvm(1180): GC_EXPLICIT freed 604K, 10% free 12042K/13255K, paused 8ms+129ms
02-23 10:51:54.157: D/AndroidRuntime(1670): Shutting down VM
02-23 10:51:54.177: D/dalvikvm(1670): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 456K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
02-23 10:51:54.187: D/jdwp(1670): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-23 10:51:54.187: D/dalvikvm(1670): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-23 10:51:54.197: I/AndroidRuntime(1670): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
02-23 10:51:55.077: D/AndroidRuntime(1689): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-23 10:51:55.077: D/AndroidRuntime(1689): CheckJNI is ON
02-23 10:51:56.267: D/AndroidRuntime(1689): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-23 10:51:56.317: I/ActivityManager(1180): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.problemio/.ProblemioActivity} from pid 1689
02-23 10:51:56.347: W/WindowManager(1180): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21000
02-23 10:51:56.417: D/AndroidRuntime(1689): Shutting down VM
02-23 10:51:56.447: D/dalvikvm(1699): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-23 10:51:56.447: I/AndroidRuntime(1689): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
02-23 10:51:56.457: D/dalvikvm(1689): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 77% free 485K/2048K, paused 1ms+3ms
02-23 10:51:56.457: D/jdwp(1689): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-23 10:51:56.467: D/dalvikvm(1689): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-23 10:51:56.517: I/ActivityManager(1180): Start proc com.problemio for activity com.problemio/.ProblemioActivity: pid=1699 uid=10041 gids={3003}
02-23 10:51:56.977: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(1180): setKernelCountSet(10041, 1) failed with errno -2
02-23 10:51:57.087: I/ActivityManager(1180): START {cmp=com.problemio/.LoginActivity} from pid 1699
02-23 10:51:57.606: D/gralloc_goldfish(1699): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-23 10:51:58.047: E/ActivityThread(1435): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
02-23 10:51:58.117: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(1435): Could not find a dictionary pack
02-23 10:51:58.207: I/ActivityManager(1180): Displayed com.problemio/.LoginActivity: +916ms (total +1s823ms)
02-23 10:51:58.237: I/ActivityManager(1180): Displayed com.problemio/.ProblemioActivity: +1s854ms
02-23 10:51:58.427: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(1180): setKernelCountSet(10009, 0) failed with errno -2
02-23 10:51:58.868: E/ActivityThread(1435): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
02-23 10:51:58.886: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(1435): Could not find a dictionary pack
02-23 10:53:59.657: W/SoundPool(1180):   sample 0 not READY
02-23 10:53:59.748: D/PhoneStatusBar(1233): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info BACK HOME recent* CLOCK >
02-23 10:54:00.097: I/ARMAssembler(35): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00009002_00000000 [127 ipp] (149 ins) at [0x419dea80:0x419decd4] in 2956444 ns
02-23 10:54:00.117: D/PhoneStatusBar(1233): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info back* home* recent clock* >
02-23 10:54:03.086: D/1(1699): Please enter your password
02-23 10:54:03.086: D/1(1699): Plase enter your login email address
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180): problem reading network stats
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing idx 1
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:300)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:250)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.getNetworkStatsDetailGroupedByUid(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5734)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.access$100(BatteryStatsImpl.java:76)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.computeCurrentTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2457)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.getTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2446)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeSummaryToParcel(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5437)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4836)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeAsyncLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4818)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateCpuStatsNow(ActivityManagerService.java:1649)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$3.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1531)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:269)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   ... 10 more
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
02-23 10:54:41.017: A/BatteryStatsImpl(1180):   ... 12 more
02-23 10:55:09.777: D/dalvikvm(1261): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 6% free 9529K/10119K, paused 8ms+9ms
02-23 10:56:33.198: W/ThrottleService(1180): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180): problem reading network stats
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing idx 1
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:300)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1282)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:831)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPoll(NetworkStatsService.java:799)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$100(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$3.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:633)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:269)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   ... 10 more
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
02-23 11:00:46.967: A/NetworkStats(1180):   ... 12 more
02-23 11:01:00.456: D/dalvikvm(1180): GC_CONCURRENT freed 632K, 10% free 12039K/13255K, paused 10ms+15ms
02-23 11:02:33.617: D/dalvikvm(1261): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 6% free 9529K/10119K, paused 24ms+7ms
02-23 11:06:33.266: W/ThrottleService(1180): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
```

And I am not too sure what that means at all :)

But I saw in my server logs that the url was not being hit, and that is the important part which means this code did not end up making the request to my auth server.  Any idea what is going wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this code outside an AsyncTask ? Were you able to query your server from Android prior to this attempt ?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeRoy yeah, it was giving an exception android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException because I was trying to make a network call with the main thread of the program.

Comment: Your server is never hit because there is no part in your code that you have shown where you are actually executing the `AsyncTask`. You have a method called `readWebpage(...)` which is supposed to do it but you're never calling it. All of the stuff in the last part of the logcat is totally irrelevant except for the two lines where you log the text from the email/pass `EditTexts`.

Comment: @MisterSquonk ah that makes sense. One question though - which View object do I pass in there?  What exactly do I pass to the method?  Thanks!

Comment: @GeekedOut: Forget that method altogether - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `sendFeedback(...)` method do something like this...

```
public void sendFeedback(String pass , String email) 
{  
    Log.d( "1" , pass );
    Log.d( "1" , email );

    String[] params = new String[] { "http://www.myurl.com", email, pass };

    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(params);
}
```

Then in your `doInBackground(...)` method of the `AsncTask` you can retreive them like so...

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
    {
        String myUrl = theParams[0];
        String myEmail = theParams[1];
        String myPassword = theParams[2];

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", myEmail ));  
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", myPassword ));

        ...

    }
}
```

You'll also need to use an `HttpPost` rather than an `HttpGet`.

Comment: trying it out now...will report back with results :) Thank you for your help!!

Comment: it fixed some of the problems, but I got an exception which I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420833/illigal-character-exception-when-making-a-remote-server-call-using-asynctask-in and I just accepted your answer which solved my question on this page.