# Illigal character exception when making a remote server call using AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this code:

```
package com.problemio;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity 
{
    private TextView textView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Show form for login_email
        final EditText loginEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);  
        String name = loginEmail.getText().toString();  

        // Show field for password  
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);  
        String text = password.getText().toString();                  

        // Show button for submit
        Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);   




        // Show options for create-profile and forgot-password

        //readWebpage( R.layout.login) ;


        submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {  
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
              String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
              String pass = password.getText().toString(); 
              sendFeedback(pass, email);
            }
        });        
    }


    public void sendFeedback(String pass , String email) 
    {  
        Log.d( "1" , pass );
        Log.d( "1" , email );

        String[] params = new String[] { "url", email, pass };


        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(params);        
    }          



    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
        {
            Log.d( "Inner class: " , "Doing stuff in background" );

            String myUrl = theParams[0];
            String myEmail = theParams[1];
            String myPassword = theParams[2];

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", myEmail ));  
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", myPassword ));            

            String response = "";
            for (String url : theParams) 
            {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try 
                {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                    }

                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            Log.d( "Post execute: " , "In the post-execute method" );
            textView.setText(result);
        }    
    }

        public void readWebpage(View view) 
        {
            Log.d( "Read webpage: " , "In the read webpage method" );
            DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
            task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.problemio.com/auth/mobile_login.php" });
        }        
}
```

and I get this exception:

```
02-23 12:29:59.078: D/gralloc_goldfish(1799): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-23 12:32:12.797: D/dalvikvm(1799): GC_CONCURRENT freed 204K, 4% free 9268K/9607K, paused 30ms+8ms
02-23 12:32:16.327: D/1(1799): 123
02-23 12:32:16.327: D/1(1799): hello
02-23 12:32:16.377: D/Inner class:(1799): Doing stuff in background
02-23 12:32:16.977: W/System.err(1799): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=hello
02-23 12:32:16.977: W/System.err(1799):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
02-23 12:32:16.987: W/System.err(1799):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
02-23 12:32:16.987: W/System.err(1799):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-23 12:32:16.987: W/System.err(1799):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-23 12:32:16.998: W/System.err(1799):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-23 12:32:16.998: W/System.err(1799):     at com.problemio.LoginActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:140)
02-23 12:32:17.007: W/System.err(1799):     at com.problemio.LoginActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
02-23 12:32:17.017: W/System.err(1799):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
02-23 12:32:17.017: W/System.err(1799):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-23 12:32:17.017: W/System.err(1799):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-23 12:32:17.027: W/System.err(1799):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
02-23 12:32:17.037: W/System.err(1799):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-23 12:32:17.037: W/System.err(1799):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-23 12:32:17.037: W/System.err(1799):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-23 12:32:17.057: W/System.err(1799): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=123
02-23 12:32:17.057: W/System.err(1799):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
02-23 12:32:17.068: W/System.err(1799):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
02-23 12:32:17.068: W/System.err(1799):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-23 12:32:17.068: W/System.err(1799):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-23 12:32:17.077: W/System.err(1799):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-23 12:32:17.077: W/System.err(1799):     at com.problemio.LoginActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:140)
02-23 12:32:17.087: W/System.err(1799):     at com.problemio.LoginActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
02-23 12:32:17.087: W/System.err(1799):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
02-23 12:32:17.087: W/System.err(1799):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-23 12:32:17.097: W/System.err(1799):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-23 12:32:17.097: W/System.err(1799):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
02-23 12:32:17.097: W/System.err(1799):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-23 12:32:17.107: W/System.err(1799):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-23 12:32:17.107: W/System.err(1799):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-23 12:32:17.107: D/Post execute:(1799): In the post-execute method
02-23 12:32:17.107: D/AndroidRuntime(1799): Shutting down VM
02-23 12:32:17.107: W/dalvikvm(1799): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.problemio.LoginActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:164)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.problemio.LoginActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:1)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-23 12:32:17.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the for:

```
for (String url : theParams) 
        {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
```

With this:

```
 DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(myUrl);
```

Also, you're not using the `postParameters` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through all the params as if they're URLs:

```
for (String url : theParams)
```

In reality, only the first is a URL. use `myUrl` which you've already set instead.